# Issues with getting a tun0 connection to route any and all connections from eth0 to be made to this interface and if not working drop

Tags: linux, virtualbox, vpn, openvpn

So I've been having this issue for a while and the internet has been mixed for a response. Sadly most configurations for setting up a VPN seem to assume you are running both a vpn client and server and have access to both. I have a provider that I have signed up for.

I know the configuration of the open vpn file is accurate and the authentication since it works on several android devices. I can get this working on linux as it authenticates and creates a tun0 interface but I can't do anything with it.

I have tried various redirect attempts from examples on the internet but sadly they seem not to work, route, resolve DNS addresses, etc. Basically the connection dies when it's active and comes back when it's gone.

This is being done in a VirtualBox instance as a guest interface and a host interface of Windows 7.

No problems with the routes on either one and no issues with unbuffered internet access on both without the VPN.

See this list of possible interfaces:

```
~$ sudo ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:05:26:53  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe05:2653/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:190394 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:70238 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:184101847 (175.5 MiB)  TX bytes:4350413 (4.1 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:124 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:124 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:36305 (35.4 KiB)  TX bytes:36305 (35.4 KiB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:final address with provider  P-t-P:same address  Mask:255.255.252.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:113 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:340 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:4616 (4.5 KiB)  TX bytes:23833 (23.2 KiB)
```

How shall I basically setup a bidirectional connection betwen the tun0 and eth0 that will not fail terribly?